# help to convert bash script from Linux to FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p19

Tags: shell-script, freebsd

I have jpeg files from camera saved on FTP server in this format:

```
/cctv/IPC06/2022-02-11/001/jpg/12/26/01[M][0@0][0].jpg
/cctv/IPC06/2022-02-11/001/jpg/12/24/20[M][0@0][0].jpg
/cctv/IPC06/2022-02-11/001/jpg/12/24/42[M][0@0][0].jpg
/cctv/IPC06/2022-02-11/001/jpg/14/15/32[M][0@0][0].jpg
/cctv/IPC06/2022-02-11/001/jpg/14/15/52[M][0@0][0].jpg
```

I have a script that run on Linux to rename and move the files in jpg location like this:
( it just cut two "/" from path -from end fix position):

```
/cctv/IPC06/2022-02-11/001/jpg/122601[M][0@0][0].jpg
/cctv/IPC06/2022-02-11/001/jpg/122420[M][0@0][0].jpg
/cctv/IPC06/2022-02-11/001/jpg/122442[M][0@0][0].jpg
/cctv/IPC06/2022-02-11/001/jpg/141532[M][0@0][0].jpg
/cctv/IPC06/2022-02-11/001/jpg/141552[M][0@0][0].jpg
```

This I run on terminal connected to FTP from jpg location and it is working ok but it take a long time because I do this from remote location:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec bash -c 'path1="${0:0:-23}" name1="${0: -23:2}" name2="${0: -20:2}" name3="${0: -17}"; echo mv "$0" "${path1}${name1}${name2}${name3}"' {} \;
```

I wanted to install this script on FTP server that is on **FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p19** but because **is no BASH installed and can't be installed** it fail with: **${1:0...}: Bad substitution**

Anybody can help to convert this linux script to run on installed as it is BSD server ?
I check and there is awk and cut ... installed on BSD.

Thank you.

```
#!/bin/sh

# BSD scripts for camera.

# OK this delete old recordings in BSD
#find /cctv/IPC06/* -maxdepth 0 -type d -mtime +32 | xargs rm -rf

# find jpg rename and move it... from linux...not working in BSD yet.
# ERROR
# ${1:0...}: Bad substitution
# ${1:0...}: Bad substitution

find /cctv/IPC06/* -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec /bin/sh -c 'path1="${1: 0:-23}"; name1="${1: -23:2}"; name2="${1: -20:2}"; name3="${1: -17}"; echo mv "$1" "${path1}${name1}${name2}${name3}" ' sh_cp {} \;


# work in progress BSD
# ERROR
# ${1:0...}: Bad substitution

find /cctv/IPC06/* -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec /bin/sh -c 'p="${1:0:-23}" echo mv "$1" "${p}"' sh_cp {} \;


# test
# this run without error in BSD
find /cctv/IPC06/* -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec /bin/sh -c 'echo mv "$1" ' sh_cp {} \;
```

Comment: which shell do you have on BSD?

Comment: @DanieleGrassini They use `/bin/sh` in their script and call `sh -c` from `find`, so I suppose you may assume it's a POSIX shell.

Answer (score 0):

I solved:

```
#!/bin/sh
# find jpg rename and move it
for i in $(find /cctv/IPC06 -mindepth 6 -name '*.jpg'); do j=$(echo $i | cut -c 1-58,60-61,63- ); mv $i $j; done
```